# Why gradient Lipschitzness implies we can decompose the gradient into a sum that has a noise component?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

By definition the gradient of a function $f$ is Lipschitz continuous with parameter $\beta > 0$ if:

\begin{align}
    \tag 1 \|\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\| \leq \beta\|x- y\| \quad \forall \quad x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n
\end{align}

My advisor said that because of the above property we can write $\nabla f(x) = \nabla f(y) +\xi$ where $\xi$ is a bounded noise.

**Question:** Why the above equality is true?

**My try:** Assume $x=y+\sigma$. Because of the Lipschitzness, we have $\|\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\| \leq \beta||\sigma||$. Now, how can I say because of the last inequality there exists such a
$\xi$?
Actually, by the reverse triangle inequality I can write $\|\nabla f(x)|| - ||\nabla f(y)\| \leq \|\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\| \leq \beta||\sigma||$ so

$\|\nabla f(x)||  \leq  ||\nabla f(y)\|+ \beta ||\sigma||$. Now I do not know how to argue that there exists such a $\xi$?

Comment: This only works if y and x are approximately $\epsilon$ close

Comment: @Calvin Khor: you mean I cannot assume $x=y+\sigma$ and I should write $x=y+\epsilon$?

Comment: @Calvin Khor: I edited my try to make it clearer. Can you please take a look?

Comment: No, $x=y+\epsilon$ makes no sense because $\epsilon$ is not a vector in $\mathbb R^n$

Comment: @Calvin Khor: I think I misunderstood what you said. By letting $x=y+\sigma$ we have $||x-y||=||\sigma||$ and as long as $\sigma$ is a bounded vector we have them close? Is that right?

Comment: Sorry, on re-reading, they don't need to be $\epsilon$ close, if you want the "noise" to be bounded then you just need $\sigma$ to be bounded.